# IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS

Tags: c++, winapi, hardware

when i include #include  to use the IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS

i get the below error

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: Mountmgr.h: No such file or directory

How can i solve this error.

Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` definition it is following:

```
#define MOUNTMGRCONTROLTYPE          0x0000006D // 'm'
#define IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS  CTL_CODE(MOUNTMGRCONTROLTYPE, 2, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

all other constants are defined in **WinIoCtl.h** file which you find in Windows SDK installed together with Visual Studio.

If you want full **mountmgr.h** file you will find it in the directory *C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk* after installation of Windows DDK (see suggestion of Hans Passant).

Answer (score 1):

It is a WDK header file, inc\ddk\mountmgr.h.  You'll have to [download the WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Win32 API [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(v=VS.85).aspx).  Please see the documentation on MSDN On how to use it exactly.

If you don't fully understand the MSDN documentation you can do a [search on Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=DeviceIoControl+IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code) and there is usually examples of its usage out there.